Passing data between components that one of them routerOutlet in Angular
I have category and product components that inside the dashboard component. I wanna passing data from category component to product component but there is routerOutlet inside of productComponents. I'm having trouble with this.
Dashboard Screen
dashboard.component.html
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-2">
        <app-category></app-category>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-10">
        <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>

category.component.html
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
    <label for="menu-toggle" class="hamburger-menu" (click)="showCategoryList()"><span></span></label>
    <div class="content">
        <p class="menu-title title is-4" style="font-weight: normal">Categories</p>
        <ul class="menu-list">
            <li class="subtitle category-list" *ngFor="let category of categories">
                <input type="checkbox" [id]="category.id" (change)="filterProductsByCategory($event)">
                <label [htmlFor]="category.id">{{category.name}}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="filter mb-3"><button (click)="getFilterData()">Filter</button></div>
    </div>
</div>

category.component.ts
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit{

  categories: Category[] = [];
  activatedCategory?: Category;
  dataLoaded = false;
  currentCategories: Category[] = [];
  selectedCategory: Category[]  = [];

  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) { }

  hamburgerMenu: HTMLElement = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu")!;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCategories();
   
  }

  getCategories() {
    this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(response => {
      this.categories = response.data;
      this.dataLoaded = true;
    })
  }
  
  getActivatedCategory(category: Category) {
    this.activatedCategory = category;
  }

  setCurrencyCategory(category: Category) {
    this.currentCategories.push(category);
  }

  showCategoryList() {
    var content = document.querySelector(".content")! as HTMLElement;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.transition = "0.5s ease";
      content.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
      content.style.transition = "0.5s ease";
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  filterProductsByCategory(event: any){
    if(event.target.checked){
      console.log(event.target.id);
      this.selectedCategory.push(event.target.id);
    }else{
      const id = event.target.id;
      this.selectedCategory.forEach((category, index) => {
        if(category.id === id){
          const index = this.selectedCategory.indexOf(category);
          console.log(index);
          this.selectedCategory.splice(index, 1);
        }
      })
    }
  }

  getFilterData(){
    const pars = this.selectedCategory.map((category: any) => {
      return parseInt(category);
    })
    console.log(this.selectedCategory);
  }
}

products.component.html
<div id="products">   
    <div *ngIf="!dataLoaded" class="lds-ring"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <h1 class="title">Products</h1>
    <div id="search-box">
      <input class="input mb-4" type="text" placeholder="Filter by product name" [(ngModel)]="searchText">
      <button class="button is-dark" type="button">Search</button>
    </div>
    
    <table *ngIf="dataLoaded && products" class="table is-hoverable is-fullwidth  is-striped" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Unit In Stock</th>
            <th>Unit On Order</th>
            <th>Reorder Level</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let product of products | filterProducts: searchText">
          <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.categoryID }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.unitPrice| currency: "TR" : '₺' : '2.2-2'  }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.unitsInStock }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.unitsOnOrder }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.reorderLevel }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div *ngIf="!products">No Products!</div>
  </div>

products.component.ts
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit{

  products: Product[] = [];
  searchText = '';

  dataLoaded = false;
  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      if(params["id"]){
        this.getProductsByCategoryId(params["id"])
      }else{
        this.getProducts();

      }
    })
  }

  getProducts() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(response => {
        this.products = response.data;
        this.dataLoaded = true; 
    })
   }

   getProductsByCategoryId(categoryId: number) {
    this.productService.getProductsByCategoryId(categoryId).subscribe(response => {     
        this.products = response.data;
        this.dataLoaded = true;
    })
   }  
}

I am expecting easily passing data from categoriesComponent to productsComponent

Create a service, ensure you have providedIn: 'root', which means the entire application has access to this service and need to be added to any providers array.
Set and read data from this service to enable passing data from any component to another easily!
If you want to call methods from one component to another, we can use a Subject to do this.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShareService {
  dataToShare = null;
  subject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  subObs$: Observable<any>;

  constructor() {
      this.subObs$ = this.subject.toObservable();
  }

  emit(eventName: string, data = {}) {
      this.subject.next({eventName: eventName, data: data});
  }
}


calling methods from one component to another
Using the below code, we can call methods from two non related components, where we emit in one location and subscribe to emits in another location, using a simple if, we filter out the methods, this is known as an event bus, also ensure to unsubscribe the subscription on component destroy as it will cause memory leaks!
A Comp
callBMethod() {
    this.shareService.emit('compBEvent', {});
}

B Comp
ngOnInit() {
    this.shareService.subObs$.subscribe(({eventName, data}) => {
        if(eventName === 'compBEvent'){
             this.bMethod();
        }
    });
}


i have two services stored separately as product & categories services

@HaktanÖzyaşar You can use either one, or create a new one, most important is providedIn: 'root' so that all components use the same instance (singleton) of the service and access the same data!

my all service use them but can't make

@HaktanÖzyaşar basically use services to share the details you need, this will work, even when components are rendered inside router-outlet!
